# Accessing the ServiceModel layer directly

Tags: wcf

I'm new to WCF, so apologies if I'm missing the boat completely.

It seems like WCF provides plenty of functionality for using the "Channel" layer by itself. For example, to create a server, you can create a channel listener from a binding and call WaitForRequest, Reply, etc. These methods all deal with **Message** objects, so it is up to you to do something with the message.

My question has to do with what happens once we've already got a message. Suppose I have an object that implements a service, described by a **ServiceContract**, and a **Message** object which I know represents a call to a particular operation. What I'd really like to do is something like:

```
Message requestMessage = GetMessageSomehow();
OperationDescription oc = GetContractForMessage();
Message replyMessage = Invoke(myService, oc, requestMessage);
```

At the very least, if I could somehow access the **IOperationInvoker** and **IDispatchMessageFormatter** objects that get created for a type, it would be pretty simple to chain them together to get the functionality I'm looking for.

In my particular case, I need to implement some simple Soap 1.1 and 1.2 services (with no WS-Addressing). I already have HttpListenerRequest/Response objects, and can route based off of either the SOAPAction or ContentType header.

I think having this functionality would also be pretty useful for unit testing. For example, I need to implement to existing clients. It would be nice to have unit tests where I could test that the Attributes on the service class are correct (i.e. that the message that I know I will be getting gets properly translated into a call on my service interface).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What, precisely, *is* the functionality you're looking for?  Your question suggests that you want to handle message routing yourself - a huge task in the context of WCF.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Added some info.. you bring up a good point about routing. My case is simple enough where I am doing it myself, but I don't see any reason why the routing can't be separated from the Channel Layer also... the Message object should have all the information required to do the routing, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Serialization/Deserialization from that Message instance to actual parameters for a call is usually done by an [IDispatchMessageFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageformatter.aspx) / [IClientMessageFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageformatter.aspx).

On the server side, an IDispatchMessageFormatter is injected into the DispatchRuntime by a custom operation behavior that the data contract serializer (or other serializer) inserts.

But... if you're not using ServiceHost, there's no DispatchRuntime. Basically, if you want all of this, you're going to have to do all the hard work yourself :)

That said, if you can get an OperationDescription object, you should be able to instantiate a DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior, but you won't be able to get an IDispatchMessageFormatter out of it... you can get an [XmlObjectSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.xmlobjectserializer.aspx), though, which might, or might not, be useful for you.

Notice that an IOperationInvoker wouldn't help all that much, since that presumes you've already done message serialization/deserialization, so it's not really all that useful (and the rest of the functionality is fairly simple for basic use cases if you want to roll it yourself)

Comment: I was afraid of as much... XmlObjectSerializer doesn't quite do the trick for a couple of reasons. I'm going to try pulling out the IDispatchMessageFormatter implementations from mono. Unfortunate, but better than starting from scratch :)